# Dagger 2 @Component.Builder dependencies missing setters error

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to instantiate *Dagger* using some external parameters (I am writing a library) but the compiler keeps giving me the following error:

> error: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or
>   components:  [com.example.domain.LibraryClient.Dependency]

Dependency is a simple interface which I use to get the *Application* in order to create room.

```
   interface Dependency {
        fun getApplication(): Application
    }
```

This is my library component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, LibraryModule::class],
        dependencies = [LibraryClient.Dependency::class])
    interface LibraryComponent {

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {
            @BindsInstance
            fun client(client: LibraryClientImpl): Builder

            fun build(): LibraryComponent
        }

        fun inject(target: LibraryClientImpl)
    }
```

and this is the injector:

```
object LibraryInjector {

    private var deps: LibraryClient.Dependency? = null

    fun setDependency(dependency: LibraryClient.Dependency) {
        this.deps = dependency
    }

    fun init(client: LibraryClientImpl): LibraryComponent {

    val appComponent = DaggerLibraryComponent.builder()
            .dependency(deps)
            .client(client)
            .build()

        appComponent.inject(client)

        return appComponent
    }
}
```

I have seen some examples that they use the dependencies option from `@Component` and it seems right. If I delete `dependencies = [LibraryClient.Dependency::class]` it passes the build. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `dependencies = [LibraryClient.Dependency::class]` as `@Component` dependency you have to add a corresponding `@Component.Builder` method (setter) too.

```
interface Builder {
   ...
   fun libraryClient(libraryClient: LibraryClient.Dependency): Builder
   ...
}
```